# Upgrade path: Can Min API "skip" a version?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, upgrade

I have an app which currently supports Android API 17 and above.

My new version requires some calls that were added in API 19.  I have finished coding and am ready to release my new version...but only for API 19 and above.  I intend to support API 17, but it will take me a little while to write that code.

I would not like to hold up the release my app for my API 19 customers.

If I upload an APK with minimum SDK level set to 19, then I know that my customers with API < 19 will not be able to upgrade.  However, if I later upload *another* APK with my min API now set back to 17 again, will the API < 19 installations be able to "skip" the first APK version and upgrade to the next version that supports their device?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the minSDK version after the app is published to play store.
Also you need to upgrade the versionCode in build.gradle file higher than the current play store version code.

Once you upload the new apk with minSDK set back to 17, user with API< 19 will also be able to download the updated app.